# How to solve this error (method is undefined for the type)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

This is my Class

```
public class EventDetail {  
   private String MemberId;
   private String Category;
   private Date Cdate;

public EventDetail(String MemberId, String Category, Date Cdate)
{
    this.MemberId = MemberId;
    this.Category = Category;
    this.Cdate = Cdate;
}
public Date getDate()
{
    return this.Cdate;
}
public void setDate(Date Cdate)
{
    this.Cdate = Cdate;
}
```

when i call the method with the object event

```
<% for (EventDetail event : events) { %>
<span class="r2"><%=event.getDate() %></span>
<span class="r4"><%=event.Category() %></span>
```

I got this error.How to solve this error where i think my class EventDetail does not show any error.

```
The method getDate() is undefined for the type EventDetail
            %>
             <div class="row">
                <span class="r1"><%= count %></span>
                <span class="r2"><%=event.getDate() %></span>
                 <span class="r2"><%=event.Place() %></span>
                 <span class="r3"><%=event.Title() %></span>
                 <span class="r4"><%=event.Category() %></span>
```

Comment: there is nothing seen to be error prone. Though its not going to solve your problem but still I suggest you not to use scriptlets in JSp and use tags library (JSTL, 3rd party or custom whatever suits your need). In place of direct for loop use <c:forEach> and to display field values of any object use EL like ${event.cDate}

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: error message is The method getDate() is undefined for the type EventDetail

Comment: There are no Place(), Title(), or Category() methods in your class that you posted here. Do you have these methods in your code?

Comment: yes i have. but only error occurred at getDate method